# How to passing data from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

sorry for my bad english first,

I trying to create a variable in controller named `$keljur` based on my model results, my code getting error `Call to a member function getResultArray() on array`, so far I know Im getting error because I failed to give variable a data from an array that my model result, so how to solve this ?

here's my controller

```
  public function index()
{
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['nama' => $this->session->userdata('nama')])->row_array();
    $data['title'] = 'Master Data Persediaan';

    //ambil data id_jur utk ambil kelompok_jurusan/keljur dari tabel jur
    $idjur = $this->session->userdata('id_jur');

    //load model utk ambil keljur dari tabel jur
    $this->load->model('menu_model', 'KelompokJurusan');
    $data['getKelJur'] = $this->KelompokJurusan->getKelJur($idjur);
```

and

```
 public function getKelJur($idjur)
{
    $query = "select kel_jur
    FROM jur where id_jur = $idjur        
    ";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
$keljur = $this->menu_model->getKelJur($idjur); // result is stored in array format

print_r($keljur); // output the array
```

**Model:**

```
public function getKelJur($idjur){

    $this->db->select('kel_jur');
    $this->db->where('id_jur', $idjur);
    $this->db->from('jur');
    
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

See if it helps you.